# allow using linker -wrap flag for defined symbols as well

Tags: c, gcc, linker, linker-flags

I've read that the linker "-wrap" flag, only works for undefined symbols.
This causes it not to work properly for function calls within the same file.

Is there a way to make the "-wrap" work on known symbols? or alternatively cause the compiler to mark specific/all symbols as undefined (although they are in the same file)?

Edited due to comment:

for example:

i want every call to function foo() to go to __wrap_foo instead. therefore, i added the flags -Wl,-wrap,foo to the linker. If foo is called from a different file than the one it's defined in - it works fine. however, if it is called from within the same file - the wrapper is not called

Comment: You seem to have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/196691). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: for example: i want every call to function foo() to go to __wrap_foo instead.
therefore, i added the flags -Wl,-wrap,foo to the linker.
If foo is called from a different file than the one it's defined in - it works fine.
however, if it is called from within the same file - the wrapper is not called